# Let $u,v,z = 3x1 matrix$, In each case, show that there are no numbers a, b, and c

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $u = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $v = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. In each case, show that there are no numbers a, b, and c.

Such that

$au + bv + cz = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

How would i go about this problem. If you do not have any values a,b,c do i just add u,v,z to see if it equals [1,2,1].

Answer (score 0):

octave code

A = [3 4 1 -1; -1 0 1 -2; 0 1 1 -1]

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}3 &  4 &  1 &  -1 \\  -1 &  0 &  1 &  -2 \\
   0  & 1 &  1  & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

[L U] = lu(A)

$$L = \begin{bmatrix}
   1.00000 &  0.00000 &  0.00000 \\
  -0.33333 &  1.00000 &  0.00000 \\
   0.00000 &  0.75000  & 1.00000 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ U = \begin{bmatrix}
   3.00000 &  4.00000  & 1.00000 &  -1.00000 \\
   0.00000 &  1.33333  & 1.33333 &  -2.33333 \\
   0.00000 &  0.00000  & 0.00000 & 0.75000 \end{bmatrix}$$

The $U$ upper matrix bottom row is $0u + 0v + 0z = -0.75$ which has no solution.

You may want to look up LU decomposition.